# Is there a more efficient way of sorting elements in JQuery than this?

Tags: jquery, optimization, sorting, performance

I asked a question the other day about sorting elements in JQuery based on a data value attached to it. The solution below works but raised another question about the native sort method used and how efficient it is.

Can anyone recommend an more efficient way of approaching this?

```
$(function() {
    var myArray = $('li').get();  

    myArray.sort(function(x,y) {
        return $(x).data('color') > $(y).data('color') ? 1 : -1;
    });

    $('ul').empty().append(myArray);
});
```

Comment: I can't imagine you'd get any better than that, though you may be able to avoid some of that DOM manipulation.

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with efficiency but the statement `return $(x).data('color') > $(y).data('color') ? 1 : -1` could be written as `return $(x).data('color') - $(y).data('color')`, assuming that values are numeric.

Comment: values are string based in this instant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're performing a jQuery selection... then getting the underlying array of DOM elements... then *for every comparison made in the sort*, you're a) creating a new jQuery element for each of the two underlying DOM elements, and b) getting a data property from them.

This seems unlikely to be very fast, just looking at it. I would suggest instead:

1) Creating a map of colors to DOM elements:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

var keys = [];
var map = {};
for (var i = 0, li; li = lis[i]; i) {
    var color = $(li).data("color");
    keys.push(color);
    map[color] = li;
}
```

2) Sorting the `keys` array:

```
keys.sort();
```

3) Creating an array of DOM elements to insert:

```
var lisInOrder = [];
for (var j = 0, key; key = keys[j]; ++j) {
    var liFromKey = keys[key];
    lisInOrder.push(liFromKey);
}
```

4) Inserting them:

```
$('ul').empty().append(lis);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know implementation of .sort() method is not standardized across different implementations however most will use QuickSort which is pretty fast for most cases. However if you have a constant(and small) amount of colors and large amount of data to sort, there are faster algorithms (eg. heapsort O(n*m) vs quicksort O(n*logn)). 
On the other hand you will have to implement your algorithm in javascript, but native .sort() method most probably is implemented in native code of the environment. 
So at the end I would stick with native .sort().

PS:
Compare function should return 0 if elements are equal. Your's returns only 1 and -1, this could affect results and performance.